# Ionic 3 ngFor ion-option value error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i'm building a crud app with ionic 3, the app is working, but i have a problem with the ion-select, it's supposed to load the categories from the database
[image]

and it does that, but when select an option throws this error:

[image]

this is the html code:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="categoria" id="categoria" name="categoria"okText="OK" cancelText="Cancelar">
<ion-option *ngFor="let categ of categoria" [value]="categ.id">{{categ.nombre_categoria }}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

this is the function

```
getCategoria(){
this.NETP.categoria().then(
data=>{
this.categoria = data;
})
}
```

i don't know what's wrong, i'm a noob, thanks in advice

the data look like this in the console

[image]

Comment: data returns from API that is object that's why they give an error. Please post your data in question how it is looking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are binding selected option to categoria which you have used to iterate. So change your binding to any other value ex : selectedCategoria and declare it in your ts.

html:
     <-- changed categoria to selectedCategoria-->

```
 <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedCategoria" id="categoria" 
  name="categoria"okText="OK" cancelText="Cancelar">
  <ion-option *ngFor="let categ of categoria" [value]="categ.id"> 
     {{categ.nombre_categoria }}
  </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```